# Object as attribute of two different classes returns two different values in each of them

Tags: python

I will simplify the project to focus on the main problem.
Below are the definitions for two classes:

```
class Event_Handler():
   def __init__(self):
      self.stream : bool = get_data_from_file()

   (...)

   def stream_status(self):
      return self.stream

   def set_stream_status(self, s : bool):
      self.stream = s

class A():
   def __init__(self, handler : Event_Handler)
      self.handler = handler

   def get_stream(self):
      print(self.handler.stream_status)

   def set_stream(self, s : bool):
      self.handler.set_stream_status(s)
```

In the main.py file, I create an object of class `Event_Handler` and two instances of the `A` class: `a1` and `a2`, each running in a separate process. They do not overlap each other and work independently on their tasks. I pass the newly created `Event_Handler` as an argument:

```
event_handler = Event_Handler()
a1 = A(event_handler)
a2 = A(event_handler)
```

In `a1` I use the `get_stream()` method to access the value stored in the `Event_Handler`'s `stream` attribute. When I try to modify it with the `set_stream()` method of the `a2` class, the `a1` still returns the old, unmodified value, while the `a2.get_stream()` returns the new one.

What do I miss? When I check the id of the object by `id()` method, it returns the same in both classes.

Comment: Not sure how it answers the question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I absolutely believe you. A1 is your left shoe and A2 is your right one. These are 2 completely separate instances. Changing one shouldn't change the other.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry but I do not change directly their attribute, but the atrribute of an object I pass to them.

Comment: How exactly are they running in separate processes? You may have *explicitly* created one instance of `Event_Handler`, but the fork to create a second process would have (indirectly) created a second instance of `Event_Handler` for that process as well.

Comment: @chepner I use the multiprocessing Process approach for that. So that creates a separate instance of the ```Event_Handler```. It makes sense why the issue occurred. How to properly give access to this object from both processes then without creating a copy?

Comment: You need to use something like the [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) class to share data between processes.

Comment: What do you mean by " each running in a separate process"? Are you using `multiprocessing`?